# Loading multiple address/immedates into MIPS assembly?

Tags: assembly, mips

I'm trying to figure out the following code:

```
 .data
  strInput: .space 50
  strFOO: .asciiz "foo\n"
  strAskInput: .asciiz "input your testable string: "

 .text
            li $v0, 4
            la $a0, strAskInput
            syscall

            li $v0, 8
            la $a0, strInput            
            li $a1, 50                              
            syscall         

            la $a0, strFOO
            li $a1, 50

            la $a0, strInput
            la $a1, strFOO

            ....rest of code
```

Basically, the user inputs a string and then this will be checked with string Foo in the rest of the code.

What I don't understand is that this code overwrites $a0 (the string we input) with string foo, but then brings it back later (the entirety of the code works) and checks it, correctly!

Also, what is the use of loading the immediate 50 into $a1?

Comment: The string input is placed in memory at `strInput`, it's not affected by overwriting `$a0` as long as you later access it correctly, such as by reloading the address into `$a0` or wherever else. The syscall #8 expects the length of the buffer as 2nd argument, hence `50` is loaded into `$a1`.

Comment: so: la $a0, strInput - we put our string at memory of strInput.

then, li $a1, 50 - we put our length of the buffer into $a1

then, la $a0, strFOO - what does this do? I thought it loaded the address of strFOO into $a0, overwriting when we saved strInput into $a0?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$a0` does not contain the string that was entered; it contains the address that string gets written to by the system call.  And, as @Jester commented, the `50` is the length of the space set aside for that string.

Comment: How does the string that we input then moved into our memoryspace of strInput?

Comment: @yokow: That's what `syscall` (with an 8 in `$a0`) does.

Comment: OH I get it. See, the 

la $a0, strFOO
li $a1, 50

& then: la $a0, strInput
            la $a1, strFOO

---- confused me. I didn't understand why strFOO would need to be loaded like that. But now I understand that the .data already has strFoo in memory (including its buffer), and we need to only load it. Whereas with strInput, our input/buffer is put into that space in memory via syscall!